# Can you tell if hook nodapia (or any hook) is being run from batch mode?

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal module which performs a soap request on node save via hook_nodapi. This isn't a big performance loss on individual saves, but if thousands of nodes are being saved in batch mode this is a big bottleneck.

I would like to perform a different action when the hook is invoked from batch mode but can't see an easy way to tell this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call [`batch_get()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/batch_get/6) and check the result. If it is not empty, you are in batch mode.

(Note: Assuming Drupal-6 here)

Answer (score 1):

If you're making reference to a drupal-level batch using [Batch API](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/batch), Henrik's suggestion is best.

If, however, you are making reference to a shell-driven batch process, which is more practical for large batches than web-based ones, you could test [php_sapi_name()](http://php.net/php_sapi_name): if the return is `"cli"`, then it's command-line and can be a shell batch. Depends on your context

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global var that you set in the start of the script and unset / change value in the end. Then you could check for that global var in your hook and do nothing if if it's set with a certain value.

Comment: That would work for a batch process that I wrote, but not for any other batch process.